# Counting and displaying completed items in function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a Jquery function that sorts completed/incomplete items in a to do list as per the function below:

```
$('.sort').click(function(){
    var _t = $(this);
    $('.sort').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    if (_t.hasClass('showall')) {
        $('li.todo').show();
    }
    else if (_t.hasClass('complete')) {
        $('li.todo').show();
        $('li.todo').filter(function(){
            return !!$(this).find('span.uncheck_box').length;
        }).hide();
    }
    else if (_t.hasClass('incomplete')) {
        $('li.todo').show();
        $('li.todo').filter(function(){
            return !!$(this).find('span.check_box').length;
        }).hide();
    }
```

How can I use this to get and show the count of completed items in wordpress. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: `console.log($('span.complete').length);`

Comment: @ubercooluk thanks but i want to show this as a button with a separate div. How can i achieve this?

Comment: just put a button in your page `<button id='count'>get count</button>` and use this code `$(document).ready(function(){$('#count').click(function(){console.log($('span.complete').length);});});`

Comment: @ubercooluk thanks..The above code doesn't seem to work. I even used this to display the count on the page but again no luck `$(document).ready(function()
                  {
                      $('.2').show();                      
                  });
$(function() {
        
    var numrelated=$('.relatedelements >span.check_box ').length;
        $('.num-relatedelements').html(numrelated); 
    });`